# Play Framework handling table information

Tags: java, database, playframework-2.0

I'm develloping an application with Play Framework 2.0.

I have a filter section, which returns several results on a table, and on each row I have a Details button like this:

```
@(logList: List[Log])

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@title = {
    Results...
}

@main(title, nav = "filter") {

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Hour</th>
            <th>Event</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @helper.form(action = routes.LogDetail.submit) {
        @logList.map { log =>
        <tr>
                          <td>@log.id</td>
            <td>@log.date</td>
            <td>@log.time</td>
            <td>@log.event</td>
            <td>

            <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Details">

            </td>
        </tr>
        }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

What changes do I need to pass a row's id as the row's detail button is pressed?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't get why are you using form even if you don't send anything? De facto for each row you should use separate form and use hidden field as Li-o showed you.

Instead it would be just easier to use common GET

```
<a href="@routes.LogDetails.show(log.id)" class="btn">Details</a>
```

In Twitter Bootstrap you can also display A link as button

Comment: Go for the stateless/restfull solution. Setting the ID in the URL/route.

Comment: Indeed, if he's not sending any data he should use GET.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden input field inside you form: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@log.id">`